# validator with generated entity persistens

Tags: java, spring, validation, web

I generated the entities from the table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANK")
public class Bank {
private String bankId;
@Id
@Column(name = "BANK_ID", nullable = false, length = 5)
public String getBankId() {
    return bankId;
}

 public void setBankId(String bankId) {
    this.bankId = bankId;
}
```

how  can i use validatior without annotation like @Size. In my case it is length = 5. I need get error when bankid bean setting more 5 symbols. I find solution here https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-validator-example/. But i don't want write annotation for each bean, i want generated column size from the exsisting table

Comment: Let us know if IDEA or Eclipse tools help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "JPA tools" served by Eclipse or IDEA to generate java entity class from tables.

some URL

[IDEA manula](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/generating-persistence-mappings.html)

[HIBERNATE helps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-jpa-support.html?origin=old_help#d998879e350)

[Eclipse](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-create-java-classes-from-tables.html)

Comment: i can't find. Can you show me where we can set @Size annotations to generate from the table